# Inserting data into SharePoint

Tags: c#, database, sharepoint

Unfortunately I have to deal with Microsoft SharePoint.

I am writing a code in C# that parse some unique format and I need to insert it into SharePoint database.

What do you think is the correct way of doing it?

The data include some special fields that I guess does not exist in SharePoint by default like a PGP signature and more.

What is the best way of dealing with this kind of data in SharePoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well apart from the "wah wahaaa" ;) you've given very little to go on (for example, you've not even mentioned the version of SharePoint you are having to deal with) but I will do my best ...

- When you say 'SharePoint Database' I am assuming that you're referring to a SharePoint list?
- Do you need to allow your users to enter/modify this data or is it read only?
- Are you inserting this data into SharePoint from another program, if so ran locally or remote?

If this is something that you want your users to be able to add/edit/update then you may have to look at [custom field types](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/customizing-the-user-experience-of-sharepoint-custom-fields-deep-dive-part-5-of-6) - these allow you to provide storage/view/edit functionality for a custom data type, e.g. ISDB numbers.

If you're talking about inserting this data into a SharePoint list from another program then you can probably just use a read only text field (which you can create programatically or via the UI) and then insert records via the [object model](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Accessing+list+items+using+the+object+model) (will only run locally on your SharePoint server) or via the [web services](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/SharePoint+Web+Services) and the [Lists web service](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Lists+SharePoint+Web+Service) (could be ran remotely).

Or of course a combination of the two.

Comment: first, thanks for the answer. Sorry there are no details because they does not exist yet. I am just checking the possibilities of working with SharePoint. In this case i can work with SharePoint 2008 or 2010 is up to me. I wanted some general genuine help with understanding SharePoint above the commercial way Microsoft are explaining. You have provided the answer i needed. Thanks Again.

Comment: You may not know the version of SP you're going to be using but I still feel that you could have put a bit more meat around what you're wanting to do with it - would have gotten a more detailed answer then. (BTW I didn't downvote ya)